# Error when adding plugin to webwroks project

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I am new to webworks development..when i add plugin in webwroks projects using command prompt,showing following error

'webwroks' not recognised as internal or external command.

please help me as quick as possible

Answer (score 1):

are you typing "webworks", or "webwroks" like shown above?

To add a plugin you would type

```
webworks plugin add <plugin-name>
```

For example...

```
webworks plugin add com.blackberry.app
```

Comment: i have typed webworks only,while posting the question in stack overflow i have made mistake.i have fixed this issue..thanks a lot